# Web page not rendering

Tags: wordpress

I just did a fresh install of wordpress and changed my DNS. It has been about 4 hours and all I am getting is a plain white screen, even when I use a proxy server. Is there some steps I missed? My URL is www.khopon.com

Comment: I get a 500 internal server error. Check your default document. If it's a PHP file there might be something wrong with your code.

Answer (score 0):

Normaly DNS changes take up to 42hours to complete and kick in fully, 
what you could do in the mean time is rename your wp-config.php file, then wordpress will think that its a fresh install,

Currently your nameservers are pointing to 
ns2.convergentaz.net
ns1.convergentaz.net

double check they are correct for your host, 
even update the mx records to match your server ip

ie: 
@    192.168.1.1
www  192.168.1.1

obviously change that ip address to match your server ip of your website.
most of the time you should get a temp url you can access while your DNS is propogating, ie:

http://serverip/~khopon/

from there you should be able to access your site until the DNS kicks in..

Comment: this is what I get when I click on the address you provided. Server not found
      @Marty
      
      
      
      
        
        
          Firefox can't find the server at serverip.
        

        
        

  Check the address for typing errors such as
    ww.example.com instead of
    www.example.com
  If you are unable to load any pages, check your computer's network
    connection.
  If your computer or network is protected by a firewall or proxy, make sure
    that Firefox is permitted to access the Web.

Comment: the address i gave was an example, did you substitute the serip portion for your own ip? if this isnt working when you do that chances are your host hasnt setup that feature.. :(